# Breadcrumb to show description instead of name

Tags: sharepoint-designer

If you are viewing a document library, SPTitleBreadCrumb displays the name of the doc lib as the first part of the breadcrumb. We have defined our doc libs with abbreviated names, which doesn't look nice in the breadcrumb. If the breadcrumb could display the Description instead of the name, that would solve the problem. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The description is generated from the ProjectProperty class by setting Property="Description".

**Try this**:

`SharePoint:ProjectProperty ***Property="Description"*** runat="server"`

**Instead of** :

`SharePoint:ProjectProperty ***Property="Title"*** runat="server"`

Comment: Yes, this makes sense, but where do I specify ProjectProperty? I am working in masterpage. I tried nesting it inside the SPTitleBreadcrumb but it didn't like that. And if I place it outside of that, it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @sbrowning Try the onetidProjectPropertyTitle area SPLinkButton <h1 name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
           <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">
            <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="DESCRIPTION" runat="server" /></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
           </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          </h1>